# Google Document Fixed Header

Tags: google-docs

My document has several sections, each separated by a header title. Is there a way to make some text "stick" to the top of a page?

For example, if I currently add a title to the top of page 2 of my document, if I type more paragraphs on page 1, the title on page 2 will move down the page, when I want it to stay fixed to the top of page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

OP has not responded to a request for clarification, but I suspect for most people a page break immediately before the title at the top of page 2 would be adequate.